# Using the backtick key for snippet expansion in LaTeX Workshop, Hypersnips and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, vscode-snippets

I have found hypersnips faster than native LaTeX Workshop snippets for typing greek symbols. I would like to use the backtick ` key followed by a mnemonic for some snippets such as:

```
context math(context)
snippet `a "alpha" iA
\alpha 
endsnippet
```

At present, in LaTeX Workshop, the backtick key gets autocompleted due to the following setting:

```
    "autoClosingPairs": [
         ["`", "'"]
    ]
```

in latex-language-configuration.json. See [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/blob/f8a8257f3fcbc02b4e26c255a68bb98b46f6a9f6/syntax/latex-language-configuration.json#L74-L101)

As a result, when I press backtick, I end up with `|' where | is the cursor position.

Pressing `a` after this expands to:

`\alpha '`

After trigger expansion, is it possible to automatically delete the trailing `'` so that one is left with `\alpha`  ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does escaping the bactick help? ``\`a``

Comment: @Mark I resolved this by doing some hacking and removing the backtick from surrounding and autoclosing pairs of LW language-configuration.json file. Please see [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/discussions/3623#discussioncomment-4678009) Thus far, it is working okay.
Thanks!